# Defining more than one CButtonColumn in CGridView

Tags: yii, yii-components, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

I have been working with Yii's CGridView and I was wondering if there was any way to separate CButtonColumns, or initiate more than one at a time.
So that each Button has a specific column with a specific title.

Comment: you can do it by overriding the view part of cgridview (you will have to extend the extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly your question, you can, just add two arrays and define your template and configuration as following:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'person-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'language',
        'hours',
        array(
            'header'=>'View',
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{view}',
            'buttons'=>array(
                'view'=>
                    array(
                        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("person/view", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    ),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'header'=>'Update',
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{update}',
            'buttons'=>array(
                'update'=>
                    array(
                        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("person/update", array("id"=>$data->id))',
                    ),
            ),
        )
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array(
    'header'=>'View',    
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{view}'
),
array(
    'header'=>'Update',    
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{update}'
),
array(
    'header'=>'Delete',    
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{delete}'
),
```

... if that was what you meant.